# Django rest , upload image with type BinaryField type throw TypeError bytes object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: django-rest-framework, blob

i set a  field with a BinaryField
when i submit , the server throw a TypeError 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

using angular 7  and django rest  3.9, MySQL 5.7 , i wanted to test BinaryField. i created a  user model having avatar as a Binaryfield.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    avatar = models.BinaryField(null=True)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = '__all__'

class CreateUserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):

        print('request data:', request.data)

        serializer = UserSerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            #user object returned
            user = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

the server logs  for the request data is :

```
request data:
 <QueryDict:{ 'email': ['binary4@vimmoda.com'], 'password': ['admin'], 
  'confirmPassword': ['admin'], 'initials': ['b4'], 'avatar': 
  [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.png (image/png)>]}>
```

expected result is : user saved and storing his image as binary data
but the actual output is :  TypeError 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: share your `request` code like `headers` and `body`

Comment: i edited my question with request body

Answer (score 0):

You have use `MultiPartParser` to serialize form data. Try below code

```py
from rest_framework import parsers

class CreateUserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    parser_classes = (parsers.MultiPartParser)
    # your code
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,i tried that but i have the same error output

Comment: @faridos try uploading `base64` instead a file.

Comment: thanks , i'll try that tomorrow, but 
1- what if it's an image with big size
2- what if i add another field for uploading  video file 
then, from a lot of resources, for binary data , people don't recommand base64 at all

Comment: Then convert binary Field to file field

Comment: 'I want specificaly to test binary field, not FileField,
i have other sample django project on github, throwing the same error:

https://github.com/faridos/django-file-upload

Comment: change file field to binaryfield in forms to make it work `https://github.com/faridos/django-file-upload/blob/master/app/forms.py`

Comment: there is no BinaryField in django forms